# How do I generate a frequency table on R via dplyr and plot its values with ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I need to do a frequency table from two categorical variable columns where one is a 5-year age group and the other is health status (five states) from the brfss2013 data set, from where I extracted the columns of interest via:

```
> hlthgrpq1 <- brfss2013 %>% select(genhlth, X_ageg5yr)
```

Thus generating a two column frame, 491775 observations of 2 variables.

```
    genhlth     X_ageg5yr
1   Fair        Age 60 to 64
2   Good        Age 50 to 54
3   Good        Age 55 to 59
4   Very good   Age 60 to 64
5   Good        Age 65 to 69
```

I can generate a summary table with the 'by' function:

```
> by(hlthgrpq1$genhlth, hlthgrpq1$X_ageg5yr, summary)
hlthgrpq1$X_ageg5yr: Age 18 to 24
Excellent Very good      Good      Fair      Poor      NA's 
     6896     10266      7795      1873       303        69 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
hlthgrpq1$X_ageg5yr: Age 25 to 29
Excellent Very good      Good      Fair      Poor      NA's 
     5779      8488      6521      1751       325        46 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
hlthgrpq1$X_ageg5yr: Age 30 to 34
Excellent Very good      Good      Fair      Poor      NA's 
     6412      9958      7977      2295       496        75 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
hlthgrpq1$X_ageg5yr: Age 35 to 39
Excellent Very good      Good      Fair      Poor      NA's 
     6366     10169      8236      2637       638        61 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
hlthgrpq1$X_ageg5yr: Age 40 to 44
Excellent Very good      Good      Fair      Poor      NA's 
     6689     11130      9193      3334      1067        95 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
hlthgrpq1$X_ageg5yr: Age 45 to 49
Excellent Very good      Good      Fair      Poor      NA's 
     7051     12278     10611      4343      1815       112 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
hlthgrpq1$X_ageg5yr: Age 50 to 54
Excellent Very good      Good      Fair      Poor      NA's 
     8545     15254     13761      6354      3120       139 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
hlthgrpq1$X_ageg5yr: Age 55 to 59
Excellent Very good      Good      Fair      Poor      NA's 
     8500     16759     15394      7643      3998       197 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
hlthgrpq1$X_ageg5yr: Age 60 to 64
Excellent Very good      Good      Fair      Poor      NA's 
     8283     16825     16266      8101      3955       229 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
hlthgrpq1$X_ageg5yr: Age 65 to 69
Excellent Very good      Good      Fair      Poor      NA's 
     7479     15764     15600      7749      3200       205 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
hlthgrpq1$X_ageg5yr: Age 70 to 74
Excellent Very good      Good      Fair      Poor      NA's 
     5491     11943     13125      6491      2721       196 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
hlthgrpq1$X_ageg5yr: Age 75 to 79
Excellent Very good      Good      Fair      Poor      NA's 
     3320      8501     10128      5545      2426       173 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
hlthgrpq1$X_ageg5yr: Age 80 or older
Excellent Very good      Good      Fair      Poor      NA's 
     3697     10285     14400      8116      3695       322
```

And that's where I get stuck.  I have tried for hours to attempt to get here:

[Results obtained via spreadsheet.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/13wYt.png)

Thanks for any help.

(This is for a specific assignment so I can only use dplyr and ggplot2, so, no reshape2 or tidyr.)

Comment: Look at the `dplyr` verbs `group_by()` and `summarise()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off: For future postings, it is good practice to *always* include sample data. See [here how to provide a minimal reproducible example/attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including sample data.

Solution in base R.

```
as.data.frame.matrix(t(table(df)));
#             Fair Good Very good
#Age 50 to 54    0    1         0
#Age 55 to 59    0    1         0
#Age 60 to 64    1    0         1
#Age 65 to 69    0    1         0
```

---

Or something like this as a `tidyverse` approach?

```
library(tidyverse);
df %>% count(genhlth, X_ageg5yr) %>% spread(genhlth, n);
## A tibble: 4 x 4
#  X_ageg5yr     Fair  Good `Very good`
#  <fct>        <int> <int>       <int>
#1 Age 50 to 54    NA     1          NA
#2 Age 55 to 59    NA     1          NA
#3 Age 60 to 64     1    NA           1
#4 Age 65 to 69    NA     1          NA
```

---

Or if you insist on only using `dplyr` and not `tidyr`, you can do:

```
df2 <- df %>%
    count(genhlth, X_ageg5yr);
df2 <- as.data.frame.matrix(xtabs(n ~ X_ageg5yr + genhlth, data = df2));
#             Fair Good Very good
#Age 50 to 54    0    1         0
#Age 55 to 59    0    1         0
#Age 60 to 64    1    0         1
#Age 65 to 69    0    1         0
```

This basically boils down to a wide-to-long reformat, SO has plenty of discussions around that topic (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47947278/aggregate-by-multiple-columns-and-reshape-from-long-to-wide)).

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "genhlth     X_ageg5yr
Fair        'Age 60 to 64'
Good        'Age 50 to 54'
Good        'Age 55 to 59'
'Very good'   'Age 60 to 64'
Good        'Age 65 to 69'", header = T)
```